# python - Cant't take the 0 from os.system() response

Tags: python, unix, curl

I am trying to check if t is equal to "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"

```
import os
t = os.system("curl -Is onepage.com | head -1")
print(t)
```

but the response I got from os.system is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
0
```

I have no idea how to take that 0 away, I've tried `x = subprocess.check_output(['curl -Is onepage.com | head -1'])`, but it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste.py", line 3, in <module>
    x = check_output(['curl -Is onepage.com | head -1'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 489, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'curl -Is onepage.com | head -1'
```

Comment: Alternate would be to use [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) module, because ``curl`` is a operation system dependent command ``requests.get("http://onepage.com").status_code == 200``

Comment: dont `print(t)` ... the value of `t` is zero , all os.system returns is the status result of the executable ... not the standard out ... you could try `os.popen("...").read()` that might be more what you want ... or `subprocess.check_output` or use `requests` like mentioned in the other comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.system` only returns the [exit code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) of the spawned process, with zero usually indicating success.

You had the right intuition with using `check_output` as it returns the standard output of the process, and handles non-zero exit codes by throwing an exception. Your example fails because the given command needs to run in a shell, which is not the default. As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#frequently-used-arguments):

> If shell is True, the specified command will be executed through the
> shell. This can be useful if you are using Python primarily for the
> enhanced control flow it offers over most system shells and still want
> convenient access to other shell features such as shell pipes,
> filename wildcards, environment variable expansion, and expansion of ~
> to a user’s home directory.

The following works as intended:

```
import subprocessing
output = subprocess.check_output("curl -Is www.google.com | head -1", shell=True)
print(output)
```

This gives:

```
b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
```